# Google API Private access

Tags: google-api

I want to create an app that only my family members will be using. It needs to access Google Drive files using oauth access (to be precise it will be PHP client).
I've set permissions in Google API Console ./auth/drive.readonly.
I realize that I'll get an unverified app warning, but anyway, when I try to access the resources I get 403 error. Also when accessing for the first time and pasting the URL to get verification code it only says that app will have access to metadata, which is default permission.

Is it possible at all to create this kind of unverified app that will have those "unsafe" access to drive?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone faces the same problem - when requesting access through an API, be it REST or PHP library one needs to specify the permissions app will be using. Those need to match the ones specified in Google Dev Console.